# jQuery - onClick not getting activated

Tags: jquery

I am trying to activate an alert when I click on Login link, surprisingly nothing happens.
    I need some help here.

I want alert to popup when login link is clicked, but surprisingly nothing happens.
    thanks,
    Mick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Client-side Authentication Example</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // want Alert to popup when I click on auth-loginlink
$("#auth-loginlink").on("click",function () {
  alert("hi hello");
});
// ultimately I would like this to be binded with login and logout link
$("#auth-logoutlink").on("click", bindLogout);

function bindLogin(event){
alert("hello");
//FB.login();
};

function bindLogout(event){
alert("Out !!!");
//FB.logout();
};      

</script>
<h1>Facebook Client-side Authentication Example</h1>
    <div id="auth-status">
    <div id="auth-loggedout">
        <a href="#" id="auth-loginlink">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display:none">
        Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>  
        (<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is executed before the element are loaded in the page.

That happens because your script is above the element in the HTML.

You will need to either move the script at the bottom of the page or the more robust way to call it once the DOM is ready.

jQuery provides a method for just that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // your code in here will be called after the DOM is ready
});
```

or the short version of

```
$(function(){
     // your code in here will be called after the DOM is ready
});
```

Documentation at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
$(function() {
  //Your code here
})
```

Because then the code gets executed after page load.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in JQuery needs to be inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

Except function definitions. Otherwise you're trying to register a handler to something that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your functions in `<script>` are not bound to the tags. 
Make sure that a JQuery-function is coupled when the document is ready. Use this construct:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
//Add your functions here. 
//Use the JQuery-Factory-function to construct JQuery-Objects, encapsulating the tag:

$(SELECTOR).click(YOURFUNCTION);

 });
```

A more powerful approach would be to make a new JS-File with your "JQuery-Add-On-Code":

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

//Your own JQuery-Code
});
})(jQuery);
```